# Including custom ckeditor content styles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

Is there any possibility to have the same css styles in ckeditor content area and in other views in application? For example i had override some class for tables in my application css but when im creating table in ckeditor it looks different than in views.
  I found that i can set styles for content in contents.css file, but there comes other problem i have all my styles made in css.scss and the best way for me is just import them to ckeditor content, but i dont know if there is any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is change the file type of contents.css to contents.css.scss. The ckeditor gem also makes things a little easier as far as integration: https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor

Comment: I would really do that in this way, but when im trying to change filename to scss ckeditor doesnt 'see' my file in scss.

Answer (score 0):

You can alter the path to `contents.css` and include multiple stylesheets. Specify [`config.contentsCss`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-contentsCss) in your `config.js` or directly when creating the editor:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'foo', { contentsCss: [ ... ] } );
```

Your stylesheets will be injected and contents of the editor will match your website. Read the [official guide about styles](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_styles) to know more.

Comment: I tried to use config.contentsCss and give there my scss file, and there is problem, i think that contentsCss won't accept my scss file, only css files are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Add 'ckeditor/contents.css' to config/initializers/assets.rb

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( ckeditor/contents.css )
```

Then you can include them via JS and erb or a js.erb file like this (More options can be included this way like the locale.):

```
CKEDITOR.replace('foo', { customConfig: '<%= asset_path('ckeditor/config.js') %>', contentsCss: '<%= asset_path('ckeditor/contents.css') %>', language: '<%= locale %>' });
```

Answer (score 0):

when using the https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor gem this worked for me

In `config/initializers/assets.rb`

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( ckeditor/contents.css )
```

In the view:

```
<%= form_for @course do |f| %>
  <%= f.cktext_area(:description, 
        ckeditor: { 
          language: 'de', 
          contentsCss: asset_path("ckeditor/contents.css"),
          height: '400px'
        }
      ) %>
<% end %>
```